# Can I cancel just the array job in slurm?

Tags: slurm

I have a bunch of jobs running as an array job in slurm:

```
123_[1-500] PD my_job 0:00 me
123_2       R  my_job 9:99 me
123_3       R  my_job 9:99 me
123_4       R  my_job 9:99 me
123_5       R  my_job 9:99 me
...
```

As I read the man page on [scancel](https://slurm.schedmd.com/scancel.html), it seems to indicate that if I execute `scancel 123` it will stop **everything**

Am I wrong, or is there another way to stop just the array job? I want the already running jobs to finish, I just don't want any more jobs created by `123`, and I really don't want to have to figure out which jobs need to be re-run if I accidentally kill them mid-way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can issue `scancel` with the additional `--state` tag:

```
 scancel --state=PENDING 123
```

or, in short:

```
 scancel -t PD 123
```

That will only cancel jobs of the 123 array that are pending and will leave the running the already started ones.

Comment: (not sure if this is a matter of slurm version but) I belive there should **not** be an `=` sign in the line `scancel --state=PENDING 123` so it should be `scancel --state PENDING 123`.

Comment: Both are possible `--state=PENDING` or `--state PENDING`. This is common across many many UNIX CLI programs. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573377/do-command-line-options-take-an-equals-sign-between-option-name-and-value) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I put a hold on the job: `scontrol hold 123` Once all the jobs reported by `squeue` were done, I was able to cancel it.